# Domains created in tenants tables associated with central_domains not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oracle-sqldeveloper, multi-tenant, saas

I am developing a multi-tenant application using a package of Laravel, [Tenancy for Laravel](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/). I followed each step for creating the application multi-tenant multi-database.
I successfully created the tenants and domain tables and fill the data through tinker and the databases for each tenant are working.
But the domain I added in the domains table is not working on my localhost although I have assigned a domain.
'central_domains' => [
'test',
],

I am using Vagrant Homestead and my application domain URL is multi.test which is working fine.
but my tables have the following tenants and domains:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0mSA.png)

How can I resolve this issue?